# Router doesn't navigate on click after converting into module from beta to rc5

Tags: angular

I have routing as below.

```
import { Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './modules/home/home.component'; 
import { Step1Component } from './modules/step1/step1.component'; 


export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path:'',component: HomeComponent },
    { path:'step1',component: Step1Component }
])
```

and app.module is defined below.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeModule } from './modules/home/home.module';
import { Step1Module } from './modules/step1/step1.module';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
     BrowserModule,
     HttpModule, 
     RouterModule,
     HomeModule,
     Step1Module,
     routing
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [ HTTP_PROVIDERS ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

step1 module is defined below

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { Step1Component } from './step1.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        FormsModule,
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        Step1Component
    ],
    exports: [
        Step1Component
    ]
})

export class Step1Module {

}
```

From home module if click a submit button it should navigate to step1 and home module defined below.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { BrowserComponent } from './browser.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        HomeComponent,
        BrowserComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        HomeComponent
    ]
})

export class HomeModule {

}
```

home component has button defined below.

```
<p class="but-proceed">
            <span id="proceedButton" title="Proceed" class="default-btn proceed-btn" routerLink="step1"> Proceed </span>
        </p>
```

If I click on proceed button it doesnt throw any error or it wont navigate to step1 page.  Both the module is imported in app.module and home component and step1 component is exported in both the module. What is the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

It won't navigate because you are trying to load components `HomeComponent` and `Step1Component` in your `AppModule`, but they aren't part of it - they're declared in other modules. Solution would be to create routing for `HomeComponent` and `Step1Component`, something like this (I'll write code for `HomeComponent` only, you will be able to do the same for `Step1Component` based on it):

**home.routing.ts**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeComponent } from './login.cmp';

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild([
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent
    }
]);
```

Then you need to import `routing` from **home.routing.ts** to `HomeModule` the same way you import `routing` to your `AppModule`. Then in your **app.routing.ts** you need to change your path:

`{ path:'', component: HomeComponent }`

to

`{ path:'', loadChildren: 'app/modules/home/home.module#HomeModule' }`

Then you can remove `HomeModule` import from your `AppModule`. This way, `HomeModule` will lazy load and this is the right way do develop your app because it provides better performance.

Comment: getting RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded error

Comment: @rajm Remove `exports` from your `HomeModule` and `Step1Module` and remove `imports` for `HomeModule` and `Step1Module` in your `AppModule`.

Comment: @rajm I'm afraid I can't help you then, I haven't encountered `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded error` myself. But, I can provide you with some links. First of all, check my github repository of working example for lazy loading, you can compare it with yours and see if there's something you are missing: https://github.com/Svrkota-S/TechLogin/tree/RC6-version/src/main/webapp You should also check https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7930 and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5964

Comment: My original question was, I am able to load the home component and from home I have to navigate to step1. Here no need to create a homeRouting since its already loading. problem is with step1 not loading from home submit button

Comment: @rajm Then the solution might be as simple as adding `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` below your button.